# where are the icon of application bar?

Tags: gnome, icons, clementine

I have installed the music application 'clementine' but the icon on the application bar (the one on the left side) comes as a default gnome instead of the expected one.

[image]

Where are the icons of the application bar stored? can I add the icon for this software manually?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is the theme you're using not having an icon for Clementine. It shows as it should with the standard theme and dozens of others. You need to understand that using themes can sometimes have this effect.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Not the theme. The application should in the first place install an icon. If a theme provides one, then it will override the default icon.

Comment: @vanadium The application did as it always does. The problem with certain themes is that they override most icons replacing them by their own set. When said set includes an alternative icon then that's the one used but when not this ^^^^ happens.

Comment: @ChanganAuto if a theme does not supply the icon, the system falls back to the default icon - which an application should have installed in the first place.

Comment: @vanadium No, more often than not the fallback is the generic icon we see in this question.

Comment: @ChanganAuto first the current icon theme is searched for an icon, the fallback is a default application icon if the application installed one, else indeed the generic icon is used.

Answer (score 5):

Icons on the application bar most commonly are installed under `/usr/share/icons` or sometimes (more traditional) under `/usr/share/pixmaps/` for *systemwide icons*, and in `~/.icons` and/or `~/.local/share/icons` for *user icons*. The latter, if installed, override the systemwide installed ones.

Apparently, the installer of your application did not correctly install an icon, or the icon installed is not in a valid format.

- Find a suitable icon (graphics file in .png, .svg or .xpm format), and copy it into `.local/share/icons` in your home folder. Create the folder if it does not exist.
- Find the installed `.desktop` launcher for clementine. Open it and note the name of the icon referenced in the launcher on the `Icon=` line.
- Rename your icon file in `.local/share/icons` accordingly (name only, not the extension).

Desktop launchers are commonly installed under `/usr/share/applications` for regular applications installed using APT. However, you can find where with the `find`command:

```
find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "Name=Clementine" {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

This example assumes you are seeing "Clementine" in the application overview. If it is "clementine", substitute that instead.

Comment: Thank you. There is neither .desktop nor .clementine in the home folder. The .local/share/icons contains a hicolor folder with subfolder subdivided by dimension. Using `find / type -d -name ".desktop"` I could not find a specific .desktop folder...

Comment: If it appears in the menu, there is a `.desktop` file somewhere, usually in `/usr/share/applications`. If you prefer to use the `-d` option with find, then that is your call. I did not you tell to.